# How to print formatted string in Python3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Hey I have a question concerning this

```
print ("So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy.") % (
    age, height, weight)
```

The line doesn't work in python 3.4 do anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 42):

In Python 3.6 f-strings are introduced.

You can write like this

```
print (f"So, you're {age} old, {height} tall and {weight} heavy.")
```

For more information Refer: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html

Comment: Sure, but the OP was using Python 3.4.

Answer (score 18):

You need to apply your formatting to the string, not to the return value of the `print()` function:

```
print("So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (
    age, height, weight))
```

Note the position of the `)` closing parentheses. If it helps you understand the difference, assign the result of the formatting operation to a variable first:

```
output = "So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (age, height, weight)
print(output)
```

You may find it easier to use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), or, if you can upgrade to Python 3.6 or newer, [*formatted string literals*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), aka f-strings.

Use f-strings if you just need to format something on the spot to print or create a string for other reasons, `str.format()` to store the template string for re-use and then interpolate values. Both make it easier to not get confused about where `print()` starts and ends and where the formatting takes place.

In both `f-strings` and `str.format()`, use `!r` after the field to get the `repr()` output, just like `%r` would:

```
print("So, you're {age!r} old, {height!r} tall and {weight!r} heavy.")
```

or with a template with positional slots:

```
template = "So, you're {!r} old, {!r} tall and {!r} heavy."
print(template.format(age, height, weight)
```

Answer (score 11):

you write:

```
print("So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy.") % (age, height, weight)
```

when the correct is:

```
print("So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (age, height, weight))
```

besides that, you should think about switching to the "new" .format style which is more pythonic and doesn't requice type declaration. Started with Python 3.0 but is backported to 2.6+

```
print("So, you're {} old, {} tall and {} heavy.".format(age, height, weight))
#or for pinning(to skip the variable expanding if you want something 
#specific to appear twice for example)
print("So, you're {0} old, {1} tall and {2} heavy and {1} tall again".format(age, height, weight))
```

or if you want only python 3.6+ formatting:

```
print(f"So, you're {age} old, {height} tall and {weight} heavy.")
```

Answer (score 4):

Even though I don't know which exception you get, you can maybe try to use the format function instead:

```
print ("So, you're {0} old, {1} tall and {2} heavy.".format(age, height, weight))
```

And as mentioned within the other answers, you obviously had some issue with your parentheses.

I will still leave my solution as a reference if you want to use `format`.

Answer (score 2):

You have problem in your syntax, near  `...) % (
    age, height, weight)`.

You already close the `print` brfore `%` operator. that's why `print` function will not carry the argument you are passing in it.
just do like this in your code,

```
print ("So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (
    age, height, weight))
```

Answer (score 2):

Easier way:

```
print ("So, you're ",age,"r old, ", height, " tall and ",weight," heavy." )
```